# Trying to connect to a remote host mysql with phpmyadmin via ssh

Tags: mysql, ssh, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to connect to a remote host(CentOS) mysql database from localhost(CentOS) with phpmyadmin via ssh.

In local config.inc.php I added:

```
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3307';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = FALSE;
```

Next I established the tunnel `ssh -Ng -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 root@xx.xx.xx.xx`
It works fine through the command line:

```
mysql -P 3307 -h localhost -u root -p dbname
```

But when I try to access `http://localhost:3307/phpmyadmin/`
It says some gibberish: "5.5.20 J���
5.5.20�p��#p-.<'J}�ÿ÷�€����������[0{=^@fa2tq^�mysql_native_password�!��ÿ„#08S01Got packets out of order"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because there is no web server running on port `3307`. You need to access the correct URL for phpmyadmin, which is probably `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/` and from *there*, select the correct server to connect to.